# Firebase unable to reconnect after exiting Doze Mode

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

**Overview**

I'm using Flutter with Firebase. After the phone/app enters Doze Mode, Firebase needs a few minutes (too long!) to reconnect. It took me weeks to find how to reproduce this issue.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Open a Flutter app and select a screen where you can call Firebase with a click of a button
2. Enter Androids' Doze Mode (Lock the screen, run ***adb shell dumpsys battery unplug***, and then run ***adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle***)
3. After a few seconds/minutes, under the "Run" tab, the following will appear:

   **`Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Keepalive failed. The connection is likely gone, cause=null}.`**
   and
   **`[{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}`**
4. Now, unlock your phone and try to make a Firebase query

**For me, the following error appears 8 out of 10 times. The connection will re-establish after hitting the "Retry" button, but only after a few minutes which is, of course, too late.**

> W/XXX.XXXXXXX(14214): Accessing
> hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J
> (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
> W/XXX.XXXXXXX(14214): Accessing hidden method
> Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V
> (greylist, linking, allowed) W/Firestore(14214): (22.0.1)
> [WatchStream]: (72436f2) Stream closed with status:
> Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=**Unable to resolve host
> firestore.googleapis.com**, cause=java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.net.UnknownHostException: **Unable to resolve host
> "firestore.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname**
> W/Firestore(14214):   at
> io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAll(DnsNameResolver.java:436)
> W/Firestore(14214):   at
> io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.resolveInternal(DnsNameResolver.java:272)
> W/Firestore(14214):   at
> io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:228)
> W/Firestore(14214):   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> W/Firestore(14214):   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> W/Firestore(14214):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
> W/Firestore(14214): Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable
> to resolve host "firestore.googleapis.com": No address associated with
> hostname W/Firestore(14214):  at
> java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:156)
> W/Firestore(14214):   at
> java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
> W/Firestore(14214):   at
> java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
> W/Firestore(14214):   at
> io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$JdkAddressResolver.resolveAddress(DnsNameResolver.java:646)
> W/Firestore(14214):   at
> io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAll(DnsNameResolver.java:404)
> W/Firestore(14214):   ... 5 more W/Firestore(14214): Caused by:
> android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA
> (No address associated with hostname) W/Firestore(14214):     at
> libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
> W/Firestore(14214):   at
> libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:74)
> W/Firestore(14214):   at
> libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.android_getaddrinfo(BlockGuardOs.java:200)
> W/Firestore(14214):   at
> libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:74)
> W/Firestore(14214):   at
> java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:135)
> W/Firestore(14214):   ... 9 more W/Firestore(14214): }.
> W/XXX.XXXXXXX(14214): Accessing hidden method
> Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J
> (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed) I/flutter (14214):
> MyDatabase | getDatabaselData |
> [cloud_firestore/unavailable] The service is currently unavailable.
> **This is a most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by**
> **retrying with a backoff.**

**The caught exception is: MyDatabase | getDatabaselData | [cloud_firestore/unavailable] The service is currently unavailable.**

**Pubspec.yaml**

```
cloud_firestore: ^0.14.1+3
firebase_storage: ^4.0.1
firebase_core: ^0.5.0+1
firebase_auth: ^0.18.3
```

Comment: try to add this issue on flutterfilre https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues

Answer (score 1):

***Edit 2:*** At the moment of writing this edit, there is a commit pending on FlutterFire git (but not yet published). So the solution will be to update to the latest Firebase_Core. **It is also possible to fix it manually in Firebase_Core package > gradle.properties > change *FirebaseSDKVersion=28.0.1* to *FirebaseSDKVersion=28.1.0*.**

***Edit:*** The issue still persists if the phone enters the state naturally (6 hours of complete inactivity). It seems this issue must be fixed inside FirebaseSDK and so far it hasn't been: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4305

***Old answer:***

I see many people strugling with this, and I have finally found the solution.

It seems Firebase is mostly wasting time on the previous (dis)connection rather than the new connection. So what I did, is disconnecting Firebase whenever the app goes to the background, and reconnecting it upon resuming. In this case, a new connection is established within seconds.

**Here is the code;** create a life cycle manager class (observer) and wrap it around your MaterialApp. Try-Catch is probably not necessary, but I will be pushing to production tomorrow so it's just a precaution.

**lifecycle_manager.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class LifecycleManager extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  LifecycleManager({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _LifecycleManagerState createState() => _LifecycleManagerState();
}

class _LifecycleManagerState extends State<LifecycleManager> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.child;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    try {
      if (state != AppLifecycleState.resumed) FirebaseFirestore.instance.disableNetwork();
      else FirebaseFirestore.instance.enableNetwork();
    } catch (error) {
      print('LifecycleManager | didChangeAppLifecycleState | ' + error.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

**main.dart**

```
import 'lifecycle_manager.dart';
LifecycleManager(child: MaterialApp());
```

*(I have also updated all my dependencies, but that didn't solve the problem)*

Comment: It still does not work, as of today.

Answer (score -1):

- Delete the application from the emulator.
- Install the application.
- Delete collection from firebase.
- Run the code again.

This solved my problem without any changes to my versions.

**Pubspec.yaml**

```
  version: 1.0.0+1

  environment:
    sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

  dependencies:
    flutter:
      sdk: flutter

    cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
    get_it: ^1.0.3+2
    provider: ^5.0.0
    cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+4
    firebase_auth: 0.14.0+5
```

**Usage**

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  final Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("First Page"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Add Data"),
              color: Colors.deepPurple,
              onPressed: _addData,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  void _addData() {
    Map<String, dynamic> addUser = Map();
    addUser["name"] = "name1";
    addUser["surname"] = "surname1";
    _firestore
        .collection("users")
        .document("nameandsurname")
        .setData(addUser)
        .then((value) => debugPrint("user added"));
  }
}
```